# Is $\kappa \rightarrow [\kappa]^2_3$ the same as $\kappa \rightarrow [\kappa]^2_2$ for inaccessible $\kappa$

Tags: set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals, infinite-combinatorics

The principle $\kappa \rightarrow [\kappa]^2_\alpha$ states that whenever we have a coloring $c:[\kappa]^2\rightarrow \alpha$ there is $H \subset \kappa$ of size $\kappa$ s.t. $|c"[H]^2|<\alpha$.

It is known that $\kappa \rightarrow [\kappa]^2_3$ can hold at a singular $\kappa$ and thus it is different from $\kappa \rightarrow [\kappa]^2_2$. However, $\kappa \rightarrow [\kappa]^2_3$ implies SH (i.e. there is no $\kappa$-Suslin tree) and it also implies that the product of any two $\kappa$-c.c forcing is $\kappa$-c.c.

My question is if $\kappa$ is assumed to be inaccessible, does $\kappa \rightarrow [\kappa]^2_3$ imply the weak compactness of $\kappa$? (Given that the question on whether or not productive-c.c. is enough to conclude weak compactness at inaccessible $\kappa$'s still remains open).

Comment: I think this is Question 8.1.14 in Todorcevic's Walks on Countable Ordinals and their Characteristics.

Comment: @GabeGoldberg Thanks for the comment. Just willing to know if it is still open or if there is any progress/update on the problem since then.

Comment: Maybe you should email Todorcevic, but I think it’s still open.